# Android Calendar API - edit/delete one event in a recurring series

Tags: android, android-calendar, recurring-events

I can add and delete a new recurring event, but how can I edit/delete one event in a recurring event using the new Android Calendar API? And if it is possible how do I update a reminder on one event?

Regards Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
// First retrieve the instances from the API.
Events instances = service.events().instances("primary", "recurringEventId").execute();

// Select the instance to edit
Event instance = instances.getItems().get(0);

if(youWantToCancel) {
     instance.setStatus("canceled");
     instance.setReminders(yourReminders);
     Event updatedInstance = service.events().update("primary", instance.getId(),   instance).execute();
}

if(youWantToDelete){
    instance.setId("ToBeDeleted")
    service.events().delete("primary", instance.getId()).execute();
}
```

If you want to delete multiple events within a recurrence, simply set the ids to some obvious string like "ToBeDeleted" and perform: `service.events().delete("primary", 
"ToBeDeleted").execute();`
See [docs](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/using.html#deleting_events)

Comment: Thanks for your response, it looks good, but I didn't had time yet to test it, but I let you know!