# How to delete one recurring event? (Android)

Tags: java, android, events, calendar, google-calendar-api

Helo,

I want to delete one event of a number of recurring events.

I don't know how to manage that.

This code removes all events, but I just want to remove one of them:

```
public void removeEvent(String eventId) {
    deleteReminder(eventId);

    Uri uri;
    uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)), Integer.valueOf(eventId));

    int numrows = this.c.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);

    System.out.println("Deleted: " + numrows + " " + eventId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this java code:

```
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;

// ...

// Initialize Calendar service with valid OAuth credentials
Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credentials)
    .setApplicationName("applicationName").build();

// Delete an event
service.events().delete('primary', "eventId").execute();
```

You can visit this [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete) for the parameters.

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888169/android-calendar-api-edit-delete-one-event-in-a-recurring-series) may help too.